# InputStreamReader.markSupported is false

Tags: java, inputstream, regex-lookarounds, ungetc

I need to “un-read” characters from an `InputStreamReader`. For that purpose I wanted to use `mark` and `reset` but `markSupported` returns `false` for the `InputStreamReader` class, since it doesn’t maintain an internal buffer and/or queue of characters.

I know about [`BufferedInputStream` and `PushbackInputStream`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/777391) but neither is appropriate here since they buffer on byte basis, while **I need characters**.

Does Java offer a buffered character reader which can un-read characters? Actually, let me constrain that further, I only ever need to un-read *a single* character (for lookahead purposes). Do I really need to maintain my own lookahead?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The two byte-stream based classes `java.io.BufferedInputStream` and `java.io.PushbackInputStream` have their character-stream based counterparts in the same package:

```
java.io.PushbackReader
java.io.BufferedReader
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I’m still not at home in the stream class naming. Neither in .NET, for that matter, even though I’ve been using the .NET classes for well over seven years now.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried java.io.BufferedReader?

Answer (score 2):

You could wrap the input stream using a `BufferedReader`

```
Reader markedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader) ;
```

The buffered reader does support mark and reads characters.